# Google "index of" pages and "Not mobile friendly"

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, directory-listing

I noticed that in webmaster tools that Google indexed 40K of "index of" pages, ie:

```
www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/....
```

I have lot of image galleries and they are stored by Wordpress default uploads folder:

```
/wp-content/uploads/cars/ferrari/....
/wp-content/uploads/cars/fiat/....
/wp-content/uploads/cars/audi/....
...
```

There is lot of subdirectories and at final folder are image files, jpg files. So now in webmaster tools for all that 40K pages I have "Not mobile-friendly".

I turned in .htaccess `Option -indexes` and google start to notify me about:

> Googlebot for smartphones found an increase in authorization permission errors

So Im afraid that Google will give me bad reputation in any case. If I leave those "index of" pages he will give me bad Mobile Friendly reputation...and If I put in .htaccess `Option -indexes` I will got 40K of 403 or 404 pages and he can also understand this very bad?

Any suggestion?

Comment: You have done the right thing with the .htaccess -index and the Google message is informational. Nothing more. Just let it go and Google will catch up. It will take a while.

Comment: @closetnoc Short and sweet, but that's the answer.

Comment: @w3d You are right! I posted it as an answer with a touch of added humor. Sometimes I just leave little turdlings of an answer in the comments as a guide at least. Sometimes those turdlings are complete. It is a semi-sorta bad habit when my attention is elsewhere. Cheers!! I appreciate the feed back always!

Answer (score 3):

You have done the right thing with the .htaccess `-index` and the Google message is just informational. Nothing more.

Just let it go and Google will catch up. It will take a while. Search engines are very slow. Drunk one-armed sloths typing "War and Peace" are faster!